# INFORMATION_SCHEMA columns in where clause query in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have two requirements

1) Use table columns names (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) NOT DATA in where clause query.

2) Transform the final output columns

Table-A:

```
id column-A column-B column-C ... column-N

1   11      12        13          20
2   21      22        23          20
```

Table-B:

```
id    name        label
1     column A    CA
2     column B    CB
3     column C    CC
```

RAW MySQL query

```
select a.* from table A a inner join table B b
where b.name IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table-A' AND
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id');
```

ALSO, I want to transform final output of Table-A and that should be:

```
id  CA  CB  CC
1   11  12  13
2   21  22  23
```

I don't want column-A column-B column-C in my final query result. Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: You're missing the `ON` clause in your `INNER JOIN` to specify the relationship between the tables.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL with `PREPARE`.

Comment: Can you give me hint using `PREPARE` statement?

Comment: You can find some examples of using `PREPARE` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table. They use it to pivot a table using data in the table, but it should give you good ideas of how to do similar things using data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.